# How to check GOGC value in Golang ?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

We know that the default value for GOGC is 100. 
But how will get the value from the command prompt.
Go env is not printing the GOGC value.
how to check the value of GOGC / GC percentage ?

Comment: `go env` prints out environment variables relevant to the Go toolchain (e.g. `go build` etc). `GOGC` is a parameter of the Go *runtime*, i.e., your program written in Go.

Answer (score 4):

To set the GC target percentage, you hand an `GOGC` environment variable when running your program. If you set it explicitly, there will be nothing preventing you to obtain it using `os.Getenv()`.

The second option is to use `debug.SetGCPercent(percent int) int`. As stated in package documentation:

> SetGCPercent sets the garbage collection target percentage: a collection is triggered when the ratio of freshly allocated data to live data remaining after the previous collection reaches this percentage. **SetGCPercent returns the previous setting**. The initial setting is the value of the GOGC environment variable at startup, or 100 if the variable is not set. A negative percentage disables garbage collection.
>
> https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetGCPercent

Thus, you'll get the previous setting of `GOGC` when you use this function. Here I'm leaving a snippet showing this in work: https://play.golang.org/p/epuPhGXmoyN

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It works properly.
Why this GOGC variable is not coming when we list `Go env` ?

Comment: Infact when i did `os.Getenv()` , its not fetching the value of `GOGC`

Comment: Are you sure that you *explicitly* set `GOGC` like `GOGC=50 go run *.go`? Otherwise it's pretty normal that you can't get it, as there is no environment variable called `GOGC` is present.